# Stop a sheet from making a window the main/key window

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have two windows in my application (document based), a main and secondary window. I want to keep the secondary window behind the main window unless the user clicks on it or the main window decides to show it (via a user pressed button).

The issue is that the secondary window has a modal sheet which makes it come to the foreground. I want to stop it from doing that.

Current solution:

- Before the sheet appears I increase the main window's level by 1
- After the sheet is done I decrease the main window's level by 1

Problems:

- My timing of knowing when these sheets occur is bad and unreliable
- The window flickers a bit

Notes:

I have tried making the secondary window a child window of the main one, however this links them too strongly, where dragging one drags the other and I do want the secondary window to surface when the user clicks on it.

Comment: That's not how Mac apps behave. I would suggest rethinking your interface. Perhaps one of the windows should be a different window type, different level (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/WindowLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000227-BAJDJEDA), or you shouldn't use the sheet.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it goes against standard behavior, so any fix would be more of a hack unfortunately. To give more context, the main window is a document, the secondary one is also a document. Unfortunately I don't have much control of the secondary document's behavior, so I can't control the sheet.